# VPN access kvm guests

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, openvpn, linux-kvm

OpenVPN is installed on my host system running kvm as virtualization and I've several guests with static/public (Bridged) and private IPs (NAT), every guest uses Samba to share some folders.

how can I make the kvm guests access from my network at home?

current state:

- HOST: VPN up and running
- 2 KVM Guests with private IPs (192.168.122.3, 192.168.122.4) NAT
  (vnet)
- 1 KVM Guest with public IP bridged (br0)
- My PC: can connect the VPN and gets the IP 192.168.122.5
- (subnet is 255.255.255.0 in each network, except the public guest)

How must I configure my smb.conf to access the kvm guests?